# jQuery .load() not letting me fill input text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm a noob at coding, and I'd like some help on this. I have a page **(index.php)** that checks if cart is empty or, if it's not empty, from another page **(data.php)** using jQuery.

If It's empty, it will say it's empty and if it's not empty, it will display a form where you can enter your name and submit.

When the cart is empty, it does display the form, but I'm unable to type anything because of the refresh. Would like a solution to this or an alternate method. Thanks in advance!!

Index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            function loadData() {
                $('#loaddata').load('data.php');
            }
            setInterval(function () {
                loadData();
            }, 5000);
        });
    </script>
    <div id='loaddata'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

data.php

```
<?php
if (empty($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    ?>
   <h1>Cart Empty</h1>
   <?php
} else {
    ?>
    <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="f_name">
    <input type="text" name="l_name">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Why are you calling your load, in `setInterval()`, every 500ms?

Comment: I think you meant to use setTimeout

Comment: `data.php` never sets `$cart`, so it will always be empty. Maybe you sure be using a session variable to hod the cart?

Comment: Don't keep recreating the form. Put the form in a hidden DIV. Use AJAX to find out if the cart contains anything. If it does, show the by changing the CSS style.

Comment: Hi @Kinglish, I tried that out, but it doesn't update when cart variable becomes empty.

Comment: Hi @Ant I have updated it to 5 seconds.

Comment: Hi @Barmar, I made cart variable to a session!

Comment: @Barmar I'm still unable to type anything once cart is not empty

Answer (score 0):

You need to rethink your logic. You must somehow know when to update your `#loaddata`, instead of calling it on a set timer.
The best practice would be to add the `loadData()` in all your add to cart and remove from cart functions.

The simpler way, based on your code would be to fetch whether your cart is empty before loading the `data.php` and only if its status has changed update it.